# How to understand a fun with = in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I know a standard fun just like Code 0.

The Code 1 is a sample code from webpage, I can't understand completely the

```
fun convertFromDomain(forecast: ForecastList) = with(forecast) {...}
```

Why is the symbol **=** added to the fun? and is the return value of the fun convertFromDomain unit ?

**Code 0**

```
fun My(forecast: ForecastList):Boolean {
   ... 
   return true;
}
```

**Code 1**

```
data class ForecastList(val id: Long, val city: String, val country: String, val dailyForecast: List<Forecast>) {

    val size: Int
        get() = dailyForecast.size

    operator fun get(position: Int) = dailyForecast[position]
}

data class Forecast(val id: Long, val date: Long, val description: String, val high: Int, val low: Int,
                    val iconUrl: String)



fun convertFromDomain(forecast: ForecastList) = with(forecast) {
    val daily = dailyForecast.map { convertDayFromDomain(id, it) }
    CityForecast(id, city, country, daily)
}
```

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-syntax.html#defining-functions, https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/with.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Block body**

Consider this function:

```
fun sum(a: Int, b: Int): Int {
   return a + b
}
```

The behaviour is defined in a *block body*. It has an explicit return type (`Int`) and an explicit `return` statement. **Both are mandatory here.** If you don't specify a return type explicitely it will be `Unit` by default and since the inferred type of `a + b` is `Int` it won't compile.

**Expression body**

If you write it like this

```
fun sum(a: Int, b: Int) = a + b
```

you don't need to specify the return type because it can be inferred from the expression.You don't need a return statement either because the last expression is returned. What follows the `=` sign is called an *expression body*.

So, both functions do the same thing. The second one is only written more concise.

---

**Note**

A common mistake is to use them both at once like this:

```
fun sum(a: Int, b: Int) = { a + b }
```

What this would do becomes clear, if you specify the returned type explicitely:

```
fun sum(a: Int, b: Int): () -> Int = { a + b }
```

You would actually return a lambda of type `() -> Int` which is surely not what you want.

Answer (score 5):

A `function` has usually the following form in kotlin:

```
fun name([parameters])[: return_type] {
    // function-body
}

e.g.
fun doubleTheValue(number: Int): Int {
    return number * 2
}
```

If your function-body is just a single-expression, you can use a shorter version of the function declaration

```
fun name([parameters])[: return_type] = [expression]

e.g.
fun doubleTheValue(number: Int): Int = nummber * 2
fun doubleTheValue(number: Int) = nummber * 2   // type can also be inferred
```

So it's nothing special, just a shorter version of a function declaration.

Comment: Thanks, do you mean that "fun doubleTheValue(number: Int) {  return number * 2
}" is OK in Kotlin?

Comment: @HelloCW No, it is not. pls see my answer! an explicit return type is mandatory here

Comment: @guenther in your third example: the type is expected to be Unit unlesse you specifiy it explicitely

Comment: Of course it's not. Copy paste. You can just ommit the return type if it's `Unit`

Answer (score 0):

Traditional way to define a function is just like what you write in *Code 0*, which consists of function name, parameters, return type and the block body. In Kotlin, function can be defined with an expression body and the return type can be inferred from the expression body.

Suppose there is a function which convert `Boolean` to `Int`, in traditional way:

```
fun Boolean.toInt(): Int {
    return if (this) 1 else 0
}
```

It can be simplified to:

```
fun Boolean.toInt() = if (this) 1 else 0
```

where the return type is inferred as `Int` because `1` and `0` are both `Int` which will be returned from the expression `if (this) 1 else 0`.